# What is the exact meaning of Differentiability?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the exact meaning of **Differentiability** of a function at a given point?  I know that If

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

exists, then we can say that the given function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$. But what does it exactly mean?

Comment: That is the exactly meaning. Anything else is just motivation, intuition and psychologysm and far from exact.

Comment: "Exact meaning" is an oxymoron. While I agree with Git Gud that the definition is "exact", I will not agree that the definition conveys "meaning".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the meaning of a mathematical concept, you'll need to be willing to introduce some of the motivation and intuition that Git Gud refers to, and the way that you access that motivation and intuition is by understanding the mathematical applications of the concept. You can try to also be exact as you go about this, by writing an exact statement that is equivalent to the definition.

I've always liked the following equivalent version, which is motivated by what you learn in Calculus I about how to use the derivative $f'(a)$ to approximate values of $f(x)$ near $x=a$, and is developed in more detail later when you learn the Taylor approximation theorem:

- $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=a$ if and only if there exists a constant $M$, called the "slope of $f(x)$ at $x=a$", and a function $E(h)$, called the "error function", such that two things are true:
  $$f(x) = f(a) + M \cdot (x-a) + E(x-a)
  $$
  and
  $$\lim_{h \to 0} \,\, E(h)/h = 0
  $$

Intuitively this says that the graph of $y=f(x)$ near $x=a$ is very closely approximated by the line which is the graph of $y=f(a)+M \cdot (x-a)$. The number $M$, of course, turns out to be $f'(a)$.

Comment: It seems worthwhile to mention that this "linear function plus small error" formulation of differentiability also works for functions of several variables. It also works for complex variables (where it's important to distinguish linearity over $\mathbb C$ from linearity over $\mathbb R$). This definition also makes the proof of the chain rule easier by avoiding the need to worry about denominators vanishing

Answer (score 0):

It means several things. Lee Mosher has given you one perspective. For more perspectives on the meaning of differentiability, you may like Thurston's paper on meaning and mathematics.

Here is another point of view on meaning. To understand the meaning of a property you should think about how it could fail to hold.

Most literally, the existence of the limit you wrote down means that the function is sufficiently well-behaved at $x=a$ that secant slope approximations from the left and the right converge to one and the same number.

Several things can prevent this from happening:

1. The secant slope approximations from the left might converge to a different number than secant slope approximations from the right.

Example: the function that is zero for negative values of $x$ and the identity function for nonnegative values of $x$. The secant slopes on the left are all 0; the secant slopes on the right are all 1. So the function isn't differentiable at $x=0$. Or, easier still, take the absolute value function at $x=0$. For a more interesting example, consider the function of $x$ that equals $x$ for $x<0$ and $x^2$ for $x\geq0$. The secant slopes from the left are all 1 and hence converge to 1. The secant slopes from the right work out to be $h$, which converges to 0 as $h$ goes to 0. So the left and right approximations don't converge to the same number.

2. One or both of the one-sided secant slope approximations might fail to converge to a real number.

Example: the function $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ at $x=0$ (both one-sided secant slope approximations blow up to infinity) or the function of $x$ that equals $x\sin(1/x)$ for nonzero $x$ and equals zero for $x=0$ (at the origin the secant slope approximations don't converge, period).